# Angular 2 CLI - load outside file from an environment variable

Tags: angular

I am working on an Angular 2 project using the CLI and want a reference a file on my local drive as an environment variable during development. So in `environments/environment.ts` I have something like:

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  configFilePath: '../../../Dropbox/config.json'
};
```

When the app compiles I get the console error that says it can't find the file at `localhost:4200/path-to-file`  The path looks correct, but obviously localhost is pointing somewhere else. What do I need to do to get it to reference a file on my drive?  Thanks!

Comment: If you move your config.json file into the assets folder, does it find it then?

Comment: placing it in the assets folder worked! thanks so much, dont know why i didnt try that

Comment: If that worked, then if you want to keep the folder where it is, you can update the `angular-cli.json` file as Ludovic states below.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `assets` attribute of your `angular-cli.json` :

```
"assets": [
    { "glob": "config.json", "input": "../../../Dropbox", "output": "./assets" }
]
```

This will automate the copy of your file from dropbox to your assets' folder at each build.

NOTE: `input` supports absolute paths.